# how to check if all the columns in the input table are empty in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a stored procedure that takes an array of rows as one of the parameters. I want to check all the fields of a row and if all of them empty except line_id, do not insert that row in the oracle database. 
In java or C#, that condition I would right like that (!(a==c==f=="")). 
How can I do it in SQL?
I tried this: 
if not (a = c = f and f is null)
then insert ...

UPD: I do not need to create a new procedure, I only want to check fields of one of the INPUT parameters that is a table.

UPD2: Actually, my question more about the syntax of similar condition clause in SQL

THE ANSWER: 
if not (COALESCE(a,c,f) is null) then insert...

Thank you, @Conrad Frix.

Comment: Which database?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the current code of your procedure. Oracle has no arrays (it has collections), so it's unclear to me how you pass parameters to the procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Coalesce. E.g.

E.g.

`Insert into table1 (...)
Select ....
From table2
Where COALECE(a,b,c) is not null`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
      Create procedure checkdata  
      As 
      IIF(Select count(*) from table where
            A Is NULL and B is Null and C is 
            Null and LineId Is not 
            null  >1)
      Then
      ..... 
      Else 
      Insert into table values as Select * 
      from table

      End IF;
       End;
```

Comment: I've never seen syntax like that. `where a, b, c in ` Can you provide any documentation or a live example.

Comment: That won't work on Oracle (question is tagged as such), I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah i guess because maybe the `IN` clause requires the same types of the data hence for a single column only. Updated.